# Ionic sortable list with options on drop place

Tags: ionic-framework

I was wondering if there's someone who can give me something to start for the following situation:
We have a sortable list (standard ionic) where I need some options on the drop place. I'll try to explain it with an example.

```
<ul>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
<li>list item 3</li>
<li name="dropplace">
 <span name="option1"></span>
 <span name="option2"></span>
 <span name="option3"></span>
</li>
<li>list item 4</li>
</ul>
```

depending on which option the user drops the list item, another actions needs to happen.
I don't know how to begin on the following:
- when dragging, create the drop place with the options
- link the dragging list item to one of the options when hovering
- Do an action when dropping on one of the options

Thanks in advance!

Greetings,

Leander

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure Ionic does not provide a sortable widget out of the box. You can use [this one](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-sortable/), for example, which is basically an AngularJS wrapper around jQuery Sortable Widget. You'll be able to capture the drop event easily and to perform whatever other tasks you need.